# Insertion Sort algorithm ignoring first element

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I am implementing a simple Insertion Sort in C++ shown below:

```
void insertion_sort(int a[], int size)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 2; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j > 0 && a[j] > temp)
        {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j + 1] = temp;
        print_array(a, size);
    }
    cout << "Final:" << endl;
    print_array(a, size);
}
```

However, this sorts all elements in my array apart from the first element. This is what the output looks like:

```
Original array:
5 2 4 1 3 0 
Insertion Sorted array:
5 2 4 1 3 0 
5 1 2 4 3 0 
5 1 2 3 4 0 
5 0 1 2 3 4 
Final:
5 0 1 2 3 4
```

If I change

```
j > 0
```

to

```
j >= 0
```

then,

```
Original array:
5 2 4 1 3 0 
Insertion Sorted array:
5 2 4 1 3 0 
1 5 2 4 3 0 
1 5 2 3 4 0 
0 1 5 2 3 4 
Final:
0 1 5 2 3 4
```

Comment: What happens when you set "i = 2" to "i = 1"?

Comment: it seems it should be `for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)`

Comment: I know it's been some time, but were you using Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen? I just ran into this same problem trying to follow along with the first insertion sort example. In figure 2.2, it shows the array indices above as starting at 1 instead of 0. Odd that it left out the >= in the while condition also.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to keep the condition `( j >= 0 )` and to change your starting point in your loop over `i`, you should start from `1` not from `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for arrays that are indexed starting on 1. The first element of arrays in c++ is always 0. Without changing any operators, you can just shift your array to start(or end) on 0, in the beginning of the for loop and when shifting down in the while loop:

```
void insertion_sort(int a[], int size)
{
int temp;
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    temp = a[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while (j > -1 && a[j] > temp)
    {
        a[j + 1] = a[j];
        j--;
    }
    a[j + 1] = temp;
    print_array(a, size);
}
cout << "Final:" << endl;
print_array(a, size);
}
```

Something else to note about this code: the `&&` is short circuiting. If, in this case `j = -1`, then `j > -1` is `false`, and `a[-1]` is not evaluated in `while (j > -1 && a[j] > temp)` because it is made irrelevant by `j` being `> -1`. Whatever `a[j]` is will not make the result true.